# Iteration to make a new column from past year average data (time series data)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, iteration

Let's say i have a time-series dataframe something like this :

( p.s. the value below is not my real data, and my real data is from 2010 untill 2018)

```
       forecast
    Jan-10  1
    Feb-10  1
    Mar-10  1
    Apr-10  1
    May-10  1
    Jun-10  1
    Jul-10  1
    Aug-10  1
    Sep-10  1
    Oct-10  1
    Nov-10  1
    Dec-10  1
    Jan-11  2
    Feb-11  2
    Mar-11  2
    Apr-11  2
    May-11  2
    Jun-11  2
    Jul-11  2
    Aug-11  2
    Sep-11  2
    Oct-11  2
    Nov-11  2
    Dec-11  2
    Jan-12  3
    Feb-12  3
    Mar-12  3
    Apr-12  3
    May-12  3
    Jun-12  3
    Jul-12  3
    Aug-12  3
    Sep-12  3
    Oct-12  3
    Nov-12  3
    Dec-12  3
```

And i want to make a new column called "avg_recent_year" which is the average data of the recent year (average of 12 months above it).

```
    forecast    avg_recent_year
Jan-10     1    
Feb-10     1    
Mar-10     1    
Apr-10     1    
May-10     1    
Jun-10     1    
Jul-10     1    
Aug-10     1    
Sep-10     1    
Oct-10     1    
Nov-10     1    
Dec-10     1    
Jan-11     2             1
Feb-11     2             1
Mar-11     2             1
Apr-11     2             1
May-11     2             1
Jun-11     2             1
Jul-11     2             1
Aug-11     2             1
Sep-11     2             1
Oct-11     2             1
Nov-11     2             1
Dec-11     2             1
Jan-12     3             2
Feb-12     3             2
Mar-12     3             2
Apr-12     3             2
May-12     3             2
Jun-12     3             2
Jul-12     3             2
Aug-12     3             2
Sep-12     3             2
Oct-12     3             2
Nov-12     3             2
Dec-12     3             2
```

I'm not sure how to make the python code for that problem becuase i have 9 years data, so i can't do it manually without iteration or it will be a long code..

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `df["forecast"].shift(12)`?

Comment: No, i'm not. that's just an example data.. what i really want is the average data from the past year..

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'forecast': [ i for i in range(25)]})
>>> df
    forecast
0          0
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          5
6          6
7          7
8          8
9          9
10        10
11        11
12        12
13        13
14        14
15        15
16        16
17        17
18        18
19        19
20        20
21        21
22        22
23        23
24        24
>>> df["avg_recent_year"] = df["forecast"].rolling(12).mean()
>>> df
    forecast  avg_recent_year
0          0              NaN
1          1              NaN
2          2              NaN
3          3              NaN
4          4              NaN
5          5              NaN
6          6              NaN
7          7              NaN
8          8              NaN
9          9              NaN
10        10              NaN
11        11              5.5
12        12              6.5
13        13              7.5
14        14              8.5
15        15              9.5
16        16             10.5
17        17             11.5
18        18             12.5
19        19             13.5
20        20             14.5
21        21             15.5
22        22             16.5
23        23             17.5
24        24             18.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a rolling mean (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```py
df['avg_recent_year'] = df['forecast'].rolling(12).mean()
```